# Real or false image formation of a plane mirror and lens

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

If an object is placed in-between a plane mirror and a convex lens. Would the image that results from the reflection off the plan mirror into the lens be real.

Rough diagram:

Plane mirror------Object-------Convex Thin Lens------Image 1-------image 2.

One image is from the object through the convex thin lens, the other from the reflection off the mirror and then into the lens.

Answer (score 1):

Light rays that pass through a convex lens will produce real images provided that $u\gt f$.

The light reflecting off the mirror will produce real (inverted) images on the other side of the lens, provided the lens is further away than the distance of its focal point. Forget about the fact that the mirrored image is itself virtual, and remember that rays of light are reflected off the mirror and so can be focused to an image.

Comment: Thanks. One quick question. Lets say the lens is 15 meters from the object and the mirror is 15 as well.
lens---15m----object-----15m-mirror. 

The reflection from the mirror is technically -15m. Would the distance between the image from the mirror and lens be 45cm or 15cm?

Comment: You would still get a real image, provided the focal point of the lens is less than 15m. That is, you need whatever is being imaged by the lens to be further than its focal point.